# Pull associated values through vlookup

Tags: excel

I have Sheet 1:

`Col A   Col B   Col C
Customer Country Value
A         USA    ""
B         China  ""`

I have Sheet 2:

`Col A Col B
Country Value
USA      Y
China    N`

I would like to structure a formula in Col C of Sheet 1, such that a lookup occurs into Sheet 2 and pulls the value from Col B in Sheet 2 into Col C in Sheet 1, so that in the end I have:

Sheet 1:

`Col A   Col B   Col C
Customer Country Value
A         USA    Y
B         China  N`

The formula I tried: `=IF(VLOOKUP(B1, Sheet2Table, 1, FALSE), Sheet2TableB1, ""))`, and I get a #N/A error

Answer (score 1):

If your countries are in column B, it would be something like:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2, Table1, 2, FALSE), "")
```

Comment: Thanks Rory - I tried this, and am not getting the results I am looking for. In Sheet 1 I have about 80000 customers, all have an assigned country; in a separate sheet, I have all of the countries, which have assigned values 1, 2, 3. What I want is for each customer in Sheet 1 to have 1, 2, or 3 assigned in a new column. Using your suggestion, I get empty cells, i.e. indicating that the Country does not exist in Sheet 2

Comment: Then it *doesn't* exist. :)  You'll need to check spellings carefully and look for leading/trailing spaces.

Comment: But how does the above formula pull the information from Column 3 in Table1?

Comment: It doesn't, it pulls from column 2, I just went by the original formula and your description of the table only having two columns.